# How to convert value(Color string) return by flutter color picker to html viewable format(RBG, Hex or HSL)

Tags: html, flutter, colors, rgba

I am having a flutter application and web application that does the same thing. Part of it is for the user to be able to pick a color in flutter for some elements, the same color should also show on web, but the value returned from flutter that m storing in the database is a string and I can't figure out the format.

For example, if I select RBGA(68,58,73, 100%) on the flutter color picker it's being stored in the database as "4285295724". I don't know how to convert that value to an HTML viewable format because I don't know what format it is in. I am not that familiar with Flutter.

For example, if I select RBGA(68,58,73, 100%) on the flutter color picker it's being stored in the database as "4285295724". I don't know how to convert that value to an HTML viewable format because I don't know what format it is in. I am not that familiar with Flutter.

Comment: it is `aarrggbb` format expressed in hexadecimal digits, so if you have 4285295724 in dec then it is 0xFF6C6C6C in hex meaning alpha is ff red is 6c green is 6c and blue is 6c, more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model#Representation

Comment: Okay thank you so much is there a specific formula for the conversion?

Comment: check the sources of [Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html) class

Answer (score 1):

```
'#${currentColor.toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0').substring(2)}',
```

**This code without -toRadixString(16).padLeft(6, '0').substring(2)- is will give 4278190080 as the black color value.
final result>> #FF000000**

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks @bilal I understand that is the flutter code is there a way to do it in JavaScript or PHP

Comment: why do you want to do that in PHP or JS?
send the result to back-end and save it as a String
then if you want to convert the result there is also a function I can give you if you don't know it.

Comment: Someone else is working on flutter application they are sending that string value, and I am working on the web part of the application so i need that color in HTML viewable format.